# How to order GeoSpatial searches, and include distance in results

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I originally asked a question, but the answer is so obvious.  From MongoDB:

> $near always returns the documents sorted by distance. Any other sort
>   order requires to sort the documents in memory, which can be
>   inefficient. To return results in a different sort order, use the
>   $geoWithin operator and the sort() method.

The only thing I didn't see in the docs is how to include the distance in the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the aggregation framework has to be used, not find, in order to include the distance:

> **distanceField**     The output field that contains the calculated distance.
>   To specify a field within an embedded document, use dot notation.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#pipe._S_geoNear

Example:

```
db.places.aggregate([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.99279 , 40.719296 ] },
        distanceField: "dist.calculated",
        maxDistance: 2,
        query: { type: "public" },
        includeLocs: "dist.location",
        num: 5,
        spherical: true
     }
   }
])
```

The aggregation returns the following:

```
{
   "_id" : 8,
   "name" : "Sara D. Roosevelt Park",
   "type" : "public",
   "location" : {
      "type" : "Point",
      "coordinates" : [ -73.9928, 40.7193 ]
   },
   "dist" : {
      "calculated" : 0.9539931676365992,
      "location" : {
         "type" : "Point",
         "coordinates" : [ -73.9928, 40.7193 ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually [`$near`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) is just sorted by "nearest" by default. Aggregation [`$geoNear`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) gives a bit more flexibility and of course modifies the document to include a "distance" field and others. As does the [`geoNear`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) command form for just a distance field.